# How to choose a output cap for a 5v buck converter

Tags: capacitor, buck

I am designing a 5v buck converter as a side project, what kind of output capacitor should I choose?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Getting that large of a value capacitor is hard with anything besides an electrolytic capacitor. Most electrolytic capacitors with a sufficient voltage rating will do fine there.

In general, the output capacitor of a buck converter isn't too critical because the inductor (L1) ensures it sees fairly minimal ripple. If the load is perfectly constant, then the only thing the output capacitor does is smooth out the varying current due to the inductor having a finite value. This ripple should be minimal if the inductance and switching frequency are chosen reasonably. If the change in current through the inductor is a large fraction of the load current, then you should switch faster and/or have a larger inductance. TI has an application note about [Input and Output Capacitor Selection](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slta055/slta055.pdf) which has some helpful equations and things to consider.

However, the input capacitor matters a lot more. Current is constantly flowing in and out of the input capacitor as the regulator switches. You should definitely add at least one small (physically) ceramic capacitor. Any 1000 uF capacitor is going to be physically big enough that it will have a lot of inductance, which results in input voltage ripple. That reduces the efficiency of the converter in the best case, and in the worst case creates large-enough voltage spikes to destroy the IGBT. I've found TI's [How to select input capacitors for
a buck converter](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt670/slyt670.pdf) a good reference for the picking parts for the input capacitance.